# What common apporaches exist for database versioning for a feature driven development?

Tags: database-design, product-features

It's not clear how data consistency is provided for different branches.

We have a large knowledgebase which is filled by the experts and delivered as updates to our clients. This data is also used for testing the product.

But if we have quite a few feature branches (being developed in parallel)  and each feature requires its own slightly different db schema won't it be a hell?

Definitely some way of populating all DBs from one centralized store must exist.
And here comes the question? What are these methods?

Now the only solution I see is to create some mapping mechanism and to save mappings in the corresponding DB, yet I believe more elegant approaches exist.

**Update:**

To clarify the problem.
We have one (let's call it master db).
And N databases with slightly 'narrower' schemas comparing to the chema of master.
I.e. master is has the richest schema: other dbs have fewer tables/columns.

Comment: Would totally depend on the kind of differences. Is this mainly old versions vs. new versions (so update possible). Or are there versions with very different tables?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your database build and schema changes need to be under source control. Instead of shipping a database file with the knowledge base data already in it, have a separate build that will do an import of the knowledge data after the database is built or altered. The source of the data could be from text/xml files.

The import scripts would also be under source control since they have to handle the particular schema for this branch.

This is going to be sort of a hell if you don't get it under control and automated. If it were easy, everybody would be doing it.

Comment: That is how it looks now. But the sad truth is that features appear faster than we write scripts. Entity Framework looks a bit promising because we already use it. I'm interested in using it for solving this poblem by providing different MSL and SSDL descriptions for each DB. Though it can happen that editing large XMLs is not easier than writing scripts =)